# Distress vs anguish

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

Is there any difference between the words (nouns) `distress` and `anguish`? They seem to be quite similar.

Comment: Semantically, there's usually little to choose between them. But *idiomatically/syntactically* they're not always interchangeable. *"After agonising for ages about the price, we eventually bought a distressed oak dining table"*.

Comment: Just from personal experience, it feels like the word *distress* is used to imply that something is the effect of stress and strain, and distress can be serious or minor. This is different from the word *anguish*, which is always pretty serious, but doesn't imply anything about its cause.

Comment: A ship can be in distress, but not in anguish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) assigns the two words to different groups of related terms. *Anguish* falls in the *sorrow* category (along with *woe*, *heartache*, *grief*, *dole*, and *regret*), while *distress* is the lead term in a group that includes *suffering*, *misery*, *agony*, *dolor*, and *passion*. This dictionary has this to say about the special features of the two words:

> **Anguish** is excruciating or torturing grief or dread."*Anguish* so great that human nature is driven by it from cover to cover, seeking refuge and finding none" (*R. Macaulay*). "I had that terrible pain before playing—that *anguish* which is not to be described" (*Paderewski*).
>
> **Distress**, in precise use, commonly implies conditions that cause physical or mental stress or strain; usually also it connotes the possibility of relief or the need of assistance. [examples omitted]. The word is applicable to things as well as to persons; thus, a ship in *distress* is helpless and in peril because of some untoward circumstance such as a breakdown in machinery or the loss of necessary equipment; a community's *distress* may be the result of a disaster or any event bringing devastation with it or imposing extreme hardship on the people. When used to designate a mental state, *distress* usually implies the stress or strain of fear, anxiety, shame, or the line. [Examples omitted.]

James Fernald, *Funk & Wagnalls Standard Handbook of Synonyms, Antonyms & Prepositions* (1947) lists *anguish* in three categories of related terms (*anxiety*, *grief*, and *pain*), and *distress* in four categories (*grief*, *misfortune*, *pain*, and *poverty*). In the entry for the shared category of *pain*, Fernald distinguishes between the two terms in this way:

> *Distress* is too strong a word for little hurts, too feeble for the intensest suffering, but commonly applied to to some continuous or prolonged trouble or need; as, the *distress* of a shipwrecked crew, or of a destitute family. ... *Agony* and *anguish* represent the utmost pain or suffering of body or mind. *Agony* of body is that with which the the system struggles; *anguish*, that by which it is crushed.

S. I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word* (1968) lists *anguish* under *misery*, and *distress* under both *misery* and *hurt*. Here are the relevant parts of the coverage of *misery* and related terms:

> **Distress** is too strong a word for little hurts, too feeble for the most intense suffering. It more often than not is applied to mental states, referring to any deep anxiety or the external circumstances that may produce it. Very commonly it applies to some prolonged trouble, as does *misery*, but *distress* more than *misery* implies at least a possibility of relief: the *distress* of an underprivileged child. ... *Anguish* points to the extremity of grief which so terrifies the spirit as to be insupportable: the *anguish* she knew when when her husband and three children were burned to death, *anguish* so great that it turned into madness.

So it appears that *anguish* generally refers to a more extreme and intense level of suffering than *distress* does, and also one that doesn't hold out as much prospect of relief by someone offering aid. That is, a damsel in *distress* may be restored to safety and tranquility by a knight errant, but a damsel in *anguish* may, perhaps, not be.

(Incidentally, I don't think that the repetition in Hayakawa of Fernald's sentence about "little hurts" is an instance of plagiarism, since the Hayakawa book was originally published by Funk & Wagnalls and was, I believe, conceived as a major updating and modernization of Fernald.)

Comment: Good point highlighting that *distress* can be used for inanimates but *anguish* can't!

Answer (score 0):

Distress - Extreme anxiety, sorrow, or pain

Anguish - Severe mental or physical pain or suffering

Source: Oxford Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

In those senses of each which are most nearly synonymous, *distress* differs from *anguish* chiefly in more readily admitting of a minor degree, i.e., being modifiable by such attenuators as *slight* and *little:* [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slight%20anguish%2Cslight%20distress%2C%20little%20anguish%2C%20little%20distress&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).